# Windows "open with" python py2exe application

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I wonder how the Windows "Open file with..." feature works. Or rather, how would do if I write a program in python, compile a executable with py2exe and then want to be able to open certain files in that program by right-clicking and choose it in "Open with".

Is the file simply passed as an argument, like "CMD>C:/myapp.exe file"?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, the path to the file gets passed in as an argument and can be accessed via `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: Oh so it was that simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use more functionally 
[argparse module](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html)