# Python Executable "Opened With..." (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, contextmenu

I've made a little Python (3.x) script and compiled it to a *.exe file using Py2Exe.
What I would like is to click on a random file in explorer and "open it with..." (using the right mouse button) my executable. My program can then use the path of the selected file.

I know such information is typically passed into '*argv[...]*', however, it is not working. I only get one argument, the full path of the .exe file.

For now the program only creates a *.txt file with all the passed arguments.

Could anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

The full code:

```
import sys

filename = "Test.txt"

file = open(filename, 'w')

file.write('Number of arguments: ' + str(len(sys.argv)) + ' arguments.\n')
file.write('Argument List: ' + str(sys.argv))

file.close()
```

Comment: What does get displayed when you print `sys.argv`?  (*Not working* is not a helpful diagnostic statement)

Comment: Oops, sorry. I only get the program path, so I get only one argument.

Comment: For a C++ application, using the argv array does work. I figured it should also work for Pyhton.
Additionally, according to a few other thread (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393202/windows-open-with-python-py2exe-application) it should work using argv.

Comment: Look in the registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts` for the file extension type you're trying to open. There should be `OpenWithList` and `OpenWithProgIds` keys.

Comment: Also, check that your program is handling the command line properly by running it from the command prompt and passing several arguments. This takes Explorer out the loop.

Comment: Perhaps this will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962157/open-with-a-file-on-windows-with-a-python-application

Comment: @eryksun The file is correctly "opened with", it's just that the argument does not seem to be passed.
I tried running the .py file from cmd and it does show all the aruments I try. The linked topic does describe the same problem, but there _argv_ seems to be the solution, like in some other topics as well.

Comment: Did you check the registry keys that I mentioned? You've already proven they your EXE parses the command line correctly by testing it manually in the command prompt. That means the problem is that Explorer is not passing the `"%1"` target file on the command line. Thus one of the many places this can be configured in the registry is misconfigured.

Comment: I checked the registry and there is a folder for the extension (*.robert). Image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36618693/Registry.jpg Also, thank you very much for your help so far!

Comment: I looked up the .robert extension with the "Default Program Editor" and I noticed that the path box showed the following: [ "_path to my program_" "%1" ], that must be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now tried adding an *input* line at the end of my script to prevent it from closing instantly and I noticed an error in the panel: "*ImportError: No module named 'ctypes'*". Some searching showed this is a bug in py2exe: [How to stop Python program compiled in py2exe from displaying ImportError: No Module names 'ctypes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970240/how-to-stop-python-program-compiled-in-py2exe-from-displaying-importerror-no-mo)
The mentioned solution solved the error and after rebuilding the *.exe passing in the file path works! So it was a py2exe bug all along...